# anti-aliased large text in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, canvas

How can I make Chrome (left side) to use anti-alias like IE 10 (right side)?

I used [this](http://jsbin.com/axezeh/1/) code so far. Do I need use a thin stroke?

[image: large text not anti-aliased in Chrome]

Comment: You can use an off-screen canvas at 2x the size for drawing text, then getImage() to scale it down. [Credit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296699/jaggies-text-when-filltext-in-canvas-in-chrome/22372088#22372088).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot control anti-aliasing.

The good news is that it looks much better in Chrome 27.0.1453.12 dev-m:

[image]

Unfortunately you'll either have to "just wait", or else use images instead of fillText.

The text part of the Canvas spec was implemented last in most browsers, *and it shows.*

Answer (score 1):

You might have to wait longer. Chrome canary v28 still has bad antialiasing [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3zVC/5/).

```
ctx.font = '72pt Arial';
ctx.fillText('Iowa 6', 0, 50);
```

[image: bad antialiasing in chrome v28.0.1501.0]

Comment: Still bad in version : 30.0.1599.101 :(